# A single "next" command of gdb when debugging linux kernel is always jumping to unpridicted location

Tags: c, linux, gdb, kernel, interrupt

When I am debugging linux kernel on a SMP CPU, pressing "next" command sometimes jumps to unpredicted location, like other function on another CPU core. Maybe during the duration of "next" function, an context switch or interruption happens.

The following is the case that a timer interruption breaks the "next" command.
[image]

How to fix the problem, thanks.

Comment: How does your code look like? Does it have multithreading? Or something that depends on time?

Comment: The code is linux kernel source code I never modified. in principle,  the kernel is multithreading running on a SMP CPU.  @kiner_shah

Comment: "Another function" and "on another CPU core" are entirely different senses of "location".  Only the former ordinarily has any significance to debugging.

Comment: Are you debugging with the help of the debug symbols for your kernel?  The ones that go with the specific kernel build you're debugging?  Because what you describe sounds like some of the things that can happen when you debug without debug symbols.

Comment: Maybe my description is not clear.  The problem is that gdb step over operation is always breaked by timer interruption or schedular routine , or some others I don't know  @JohnBollinger

Comment: Ok, @river, you sound certain about that in your comment, but entirely *un*certain about it in the question itself.  The stack trace helps, but does not entirely mitigate that.

Comment: What software suit are you using for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Your *problem* is that the linux kernel is still operating, so when you release your thread within that kernel, a great many things happen which disrupt your debug flow.

This is part of the story about why *kernel development is hard*, and is a story shared in virtually every kernel environment.  The plethora of tools, such as dtrace, are meant to deal with this complexity.

In the kernel documentation, it suggests creating a virtual machine under qemu for basic debugging.  This permits a lot of flexibility in narrowing the activity and devices to things you are truly interested in.   It also simplifies limiting the number of cpus, which in turn limits the number of things that can happen while waiting for a breakpoint.

In the end, kernel-gdb is not a jtag, nor a stop-mode debugger.   If your debugging problem can't deal with that (ie. turn of interrupts at the start of the area, run through it until your bug happens ); you might have to look at trace-based debugging.